# Stuck at boot logo due to removal of all nvidia drivers in deepin 15.6. What to do?

Tags: linux, boot, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I mistakenly removed all of my NVidia drivers in my Deepin 15.6. After which, I restarted my laptop, but I'm unable to boot into the desktop environment.

Also, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> does nothing, i.e. terminal is also not opening up. I used the command :

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

There is nothing in recovery mode, and advanced option recovery mode.

How can I solve this issue, as all my data is there in linux and it is very well setup with all my required packages?

Comment: Can anyone help me to rectify this?

Comment: Did you try single-user mode yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What is that and How to do that? I booted into both the recovery modes, though. But, nothing helpful was there.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Fixed the problem using single mode and reinstalling drivers using 'Deepin Graphics Driver Manager' and booting back to single mode and then booting normally. Thanks, But, Removed Deepin. Now using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booted into single mode by using this method -

1. Goto ‘*advanced options*’ for Deepin.
2. Press ‘*e*’ on the first kernel entry.
3. Find the line ending with ‘*ro quiet splash*’ and add ‘*single*’ after that with a space.
4. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot into *single* mode.
5. Install / Open **Deepin Graphics Driver Manager** and Select *NVidia* in that.
6. Reboot and again boot back to *single* mode.
7. Follow on-screen instructions to successfully install the drivers.
8. Now, you’ll be able to boot normally to your Deepin desktop.

But, Now installed *Ubuntu 18.04*, deleting Deepin after taking all the needed stuff.